# Options to replace slow SQL generated by Entity Framework 6

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I've been using Entity Framework 6 code first to do some simple CRUD operations on my domain model and it's performed admirably so far.

I've now come across a situation where I'm performing a reasonably complicated query which involves filtering and paging of the results. The query generated by EF 6 is pretty bad and is horribly inefficient when compared to something I can hand-crank myself. Here's the generated SQL, which executes in ~17 seconds:

```
SELECT TOP ( 15 )
        [Project1].[Branch] AS [Branch] ,
        [Project1].[Salesman] AS [Salesman] ,
        [Project1].[Status] AS [Status] ,
        [Project1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID] ,
        [Project1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated] ,
        [Project1].[DateCompleted] AS [DateCompleted] ,
        [Project1].[RegNumber] AS [RegNumber] ,
        [Project1].[Make] AS [Make] ,
        [Project1].[Model] AS [Model] ,
        [Project1].[Spec] AS [Spec] ,
        [Project1].[Title] AS [Title] ,
        [Project1].[Firstname] AS [Firstname] ,
        [Project1].[Surname] AS [Surname] ,
        [Project1].[Address1] AS [Address1] ,
        [Project1].[Address2] AS [Address2] ,
        [Project1].[Address3] AS [Address3] ,
        [Project1].[Town] AS [Town] ,
        [Project1].[County] AS [County] ,
        [Project1].[Postcode] AS [Postcode] ,
        [Project1].[HomePhone] AS [HomePhone] ,
        [Project1].[WorkPhone] AS [WorkPhone] ,
        [Project1].[MobilePhone] AS [MobilePhone] ,
        [Project1].[EMailAddress] AS [EMailAddress] ,
        [Project1].[AllowMarketing] AS [AllowMarketing] ,
        [Project1].[Manager] AS [Manager] ,
        [Project1].[FK_BranchID] AS [FK_BranchID]
FROM    ( SELECT    [Project1].[Branch] AS [Branch] ,
                    [Project1].[Salesman] AS [Salesman] ,
                    [Project1].[Status] AS [Status] ,
                    [Project1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID] ,
                    [Project1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated] ,
                    [Project1].[DateCompleted] AS [DateCompleted] ,
                    [Project1].[RegNumber] AS [RegNumber] ,
                    [Project1].[Make] AS [Make] ,
                    [Project1].[Model] AS [Model] ,
                    [Project1].[Spec] AS [Spec] ,
                    [Project1].[Title] AS [Title] ,
                    [Project1].[Firstname] AS [Firstname] ,
                    [Project1].[Surname] AS [Surname] ,
                    [Project1].[Address1] AS [Address1] ,
                    [Project1].[Address2] AS [Address2] ,
                    [Project1].[Address3] AS [Address3] ,
                    [Project1].[Town] AS [Town] ,
                    [Project1].[County] AS [County] ,
                    [Project1].[Postcode] AS [Postcode] ,
                    [Project1].[HomePhone] AS [HomePhone] ,
                    [Project1].[WorkPhone] AS [WorkPhone] ,
                    [Project1].[MobilePhone] AS [MobilePhone] ,
                    [Project1].[EMailAddress] AS [EMailAddress] ,
                    [Project1].[AllowMarketing] AS [AllowMarketing] ,
                    [Project1].[Manager] AS [Manager] ,
                    [Project1].[FK_BranchID] AS [FK_BranchID] ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [Project1].[DateCreated] DESC ) AS [row_number]
          FROM      ( SELECT    [Extent1].[Branch] AS [Branch] ,
                                [Extent1].[Salesman] AS [Salesman] ,
                                [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status] ,
                                [Extent1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID] ,
                                [Extent1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated] ,
                                [Extent1].[DateCompleted] AS [DateCompleted] ,
                                [Extent1].[RegNumber] AS [RegNumber] ,
                                [Extent1].[Make] AS [Make] ,
                                [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model] ,
                                [Extent1].[Spec] AS [Spec] ,
                                [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title] ,
                                [Extent1].[Firstname] AS [Firstname] ,
                                [Extent1].[Surname] AS [Surname] ,
                                [Extent1].[Address1] AS [Address1] ,
                                [Extent1].[Address2] AS [Address2] ,
                                [Extent1].[Address3] AS [Address3] ,
                                [Extent1].[Town] AS [Town] ,
                                [Extent1].[County] AS [County] ,
                                [Extent1].[Postcode] AS [Postcode] ,
                                [Extent1].[HomePhone] AS [HomePhone] ,
                                [Extent1].[WorkPhone] AS [WorkPhone] ,
                                [Extent1].[MobilePhone] AS [MobilePhone] ,
                                [Extent1].[EMailAddress] AS [EMailAddress] ,
                                [Extent1].[AllowMarketing] AS [AllowMarketing] ,
                                [Extent1].[Manager] AS [Manager] ,
                                [Extent1].[FK_BranchID] AS [FK_BranchID]
                      FROM      ( SELECT    [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Branch] AS [Branch] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Salesman] AS [Salesman] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Status] AS [Status] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[OrderID] AS [OrderID] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[DateCompleted] AS [DateCompleted] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[RegNumber] AS [RegNumber] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Make] AS [Make] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Model] AS [Model] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Spec] AS [Spec] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Title] AS [Title] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Firstname] AS [Firstname] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Surname] AS [Surname] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Address1] AS [Address1] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Address2] AS [Address2] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Address3] AS [Address3] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Town] AS [Town] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[County] AS [County] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Postcode] AS [Postcode] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[HomePhone] AS [HomePhone] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[WorkPhone] AS [WorkPhone] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[MobilePhone] AS [MobilePhone] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[EMailAddress] AS [EMailAddress] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[AllowMarketing] AS [AllowMarketing] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[Manager] AS [Manager] ,
                                            [vw_CS_OrderDetails].[FK_BranchID] AS [FK_BranchID]
                                  FROM      [dbo].[vw_CS_OrderDetails] AS [vw_CS_OrderDetails]
                                ) AS [Extent1]
                      WHERE     UPPER([Extent1].[RegNumber]) LIKE '%SD59BBO%'
                                ESCAPE N'~'
                    ) AS [Project1]
        ) AS [Project1]
WHERE   [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[DateCreated] DESC
```

The hand-cranked version of this is way smaller and completes in less than a second.

Given the horrible inefficiency of the first query, is there any way I can influence EF 6 in the query it creates?

I may have to resort to a stored procedure, are there any good patterns out there for integrating EF code first with stored procedures?

**Edit**: As per the request from Wahid Bitar, here is the LINQ I use to create the above SQL.

```
var query = _dbSet
            .Where(o => o.RegNumber.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm))
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCreated)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(pageSize);
```

In truth it's a little spread out among some helper methods, but that's mainly it. `ToList()` is eventually called on `query`, enumerating the result set.

**Edit**: As requested the hand-cranked SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DateCreated DESC ) AS RowNum
      ,[Branch]
      ,[Salesman]
      ,[Status]
      ,[OrderID]
      ,[DateCreated]
      ,[DateCompleted]
      ,[RegNumber]
      ,[Make]
      ,[Model]
      ,[Spec]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Firstname]
      ,[Surname]
      ,[Address1]
      ,[Address2]
      ,[Address3]
      ,[Town]
      ,[County]
      ,[Postcode]
      ,[HomePhone]
      ,[WorkPhone]
      ,[MobilePhone]
      ,[EMailAddress]
      ,[AllowMarketing]
      ,[Manager]
      ,[FK_BranchID]
  FROM [SalesmanOffice2].[dbo].[vw_CS_OrderDetails]
  WHERE RegNumber LIKE '%SD59BBO%'
) AS NumberedRows
WHERE NumberedRows.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 15 ORDER BY RowNum
```

Comment: May you please add the c# linq code that you write to get this Sql query.

Comment: What's your manual query look like?

Comment: From your naming convention, it appears that you are running this over a view. I've found that EF adds all columns even if they aren't needed or mapped in the model for views. You may be able to optimize this by hitting the underlying table directly. In addition, the view is likely not indexed which is where accessing the table directly may offer a perf improvement. On such a simple query, a missing index is the only way I see EF being this far off in terms of performance.

Comment: If you do end up hand crafting the SQL in a stored proc, consider using a full text index instead of the LIKE clause. Also, your manual query doesn't include a wildcard in the like clause. Are you sure you want contains and are comparing apples to apples?

Comment: Neither query contains wildcards for RegNumber, so excepting the earlier stated omission of UPPER in the manual query, I think I'm comparing apples to apples. Admittedly adding wildcards to both slows both down. The full text index might be a solution I would look at, unfortunately this is a view on a database outside my control. I admit that performance may never be great with no text index.

Comment: Have you considered updating EF? 6 is superseeded and I think sql generation was one of the points they fixed for some stuff. Also note as per my answer your EF code contains an order by - the manual query does not. Top and order by means materializing it all into a temp table, so there is a hugh differnce. Finding the first x rows by order is more complex than just returning the first x rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jim Wooley highlighted, I do not have a full text index on the columns that I am attempting to do partial matches on. Given that the view is very large this means that every row is being compared without the aid of an index. I have not yet tested these queries on a view with text indexing enabled so cannot say for certain, but I have tested that when the search term exactly matches the column and I'm using an equality operator, e.g.:

```
WHERE RegNumber = 'SD59BBO'
```

With all other things being the same, the query executes in far more desirable times.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in your EF query you call `ToUpper`, however you are not doing this in your manual query.  If `RegNumber` is an indexed field, passing it to SQL's `UPPER` function before doing your comparison will make it unable to use that index.  This is probably the reason the performance is worse.

You probably have the `ToUpper` in there because .Net's String comparisons are case sensitive.  However, when performing an EF query, it just translates that to the SQL comparison.  So since SQL is not case sensitive (by default), EF is not case sensitive.

Take out that call to `ToUpper` and see if that improves performance.

**Edit**

It also looks like EF is treating `SD57WBO` as unicode.  This can throw off your indexes as well.

What is the datatype of `RegNumber`?  If it is `varchar`/`char` and not `nvarchar`/`nchar`, you may need to specify the column is not unicode.  In EF Code First, Fluent API, you need use the command [`IsUnicode(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696416%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) on your property.

Comment: Agreed, and good spot. Unfortunately, it's not made a huge difference. I've removed UPPER from the EF query and it's maybe 2 seconds faster and added UPPER also to the manual query and it's about a second slower. Still a big difference and thinking it could be something else.

Comment: What makes you mention the Unicode issue? RegNumber is a C# string and in the DB it's a varchar(10)

Comment: `ESCAPE N'~'` Looks like something done to deal with Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add that the order by is different. Given that there is a top clause it may force a materialization before top. There is no order by in the manual query. I am sure if you remove the order by you get simpler SQL...

Which by now basically means you really compare 2 different queries. Sorry, but what is left of the question now that cadrell0 and me point out semantic differences? One is slower - yes. SQL is crap - yes. But hey, you do different things, which is where the speed difference comes from.

Comment: The order by in the manual query is OVER ( ORDER BY DateCreated ) I had previously omitted the DESC though.

Comment: Then you are stuck. YOu hit a limitation of the not too smart ql generation of EF - one of the significnat issues it sadly has. The over semantics are not something they support - there are times EF is better made to hit a SP Or special view as some things can not be expressed nicely through it.

Comment: I have updated EF to the latest version, alas, I've gone a different route with this one as the probability of me being allowed a full text index on these tables is very slim. Thanks for the help in any case!

Comment: You are welcome. I am stuck in the same - I wish EF would be more serious in actually doing well what it does. Anything moer complex than simple SQL can not be expressed, and even in the ORM area there are serious limitations. Well... one can hope...